# How to get user's name from the database? MYSQLI newbie

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

After lots of sweat and struggle I managed to get it working ~somehow~. Although I don't know how to program something that will check user's name based on their password that the user entered previously. Any help? I want to set the name as session's name or something, I think that's more 'secure'.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start(); 
$host="localhost";
$user="x";
$pass="x";
$db="x";
$tbl_name="users";

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

$mypassword=$_POST['code'];

$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$mypassword = $mysqli->real_escape_string($mypassword);
$encrypt_password=md5($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE password='$encrypt_password'";
$result=$mysqli->query($sql);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count==1) {



$_SESSION['mypassword']="$mypassword";
header("index/index.php");

}   
}
?>
```

Comment: Believe me, you don't want to do this `$_SESSION['mypassword']="$mypassword";` - Google what is called "sessions hijacking". Yet alone MD5, no longer safe to use as a password hashing function.

Comment: That's why I want to grab user's name, set it as the session and then check if it exists, etc.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Check user based on their password? Set the name, well use the name replacement you did for `$_SESSION['mypassword']="$mypassword";` - `$_SESSION['user']="$username";` *n'est-ce pas?* Or whatever is assigned to that username.

Comment: I don't know how to build the query. $sql="SELECT name FROM $tbl_name WHERE password='$encrypt_password'"; And what next?

Comment: Where does `$myusername` come from?

Comment: It's something I forgot to delete. All the user enters is their password, that's why I need to grab their name from the database.

Comment: Getting the username from the password is wrong. What if two users have the same password? The user should enter their name and password on the login screen, and then you use `SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username = '$myusername' AND password = '$encrypt_password'`

Comment: You don't want to check *just* the password in that SQL query.  You want to check *both* the username *and* the password.  Otherwise they'll be able to login as *any user* who has the password they entered.

Comment: The website will be used by three people (no registration, too), so it won't happen.

Comment: *"The website will be used by three people (no registration, too), so it won't happen."* - yeah well, I hope you've got it protected under `.htaccess`. Once your site is live on the web and someone finds it, you won't like it. MD5 shouldn't be used here, in any case. Your question is unclear, sorry. I can't help anymore. You guys take over. Edit: There, you have been given an answer, same as @Barmar suggested and I, but deleted my comment.

Comment: OK, so you don't want to look up usernames. In that case, I think the query you wrote should work. What problem are you having with it?

Comment: So many things wrong with this code. 1) SQL Injection - 2a) Incorrect hash method - 2b) No Salt - 3) Validation query does not account for user.

Comment: "I don't know how to program something that will check user's name based on their password." This is my question. It's pretty clear. Thanks for trying to help nevertheless.

Comment: @Lnvz You use the username to *fetch* the password hash *and* the salt. Then you apply the salt and the hash function to the plain password entered. If it matches the password hash from the database, success!

Comment: I don't want to use any usernames on this website. That's the point.

Comment: If you are a) only validating password and no username and b) using an outdated password encryption, may as well just hardcode three plain text passwords in your php file...makes about as much sense as what you are trying to do.....aka, almost as much security as not having any at all...

Comment: There is no guarantee that a 'password' is unique among users. To eliminate the username/password intersection is really the same logging on 'by secret username'..

Comment: @user2864740 He could put a unique key on the password field to ensure it.

Comment: I guarantee that the password is unique among users.

Comment: @Barmar Awesome. Now I only have to change my password until I find a "can't change password, constraint violation" error! :}

Comment: @Lnvz You're basically treating the password as a username.

Comment: @Barmar Yes. That's exactly what I'm doing. I'd like to boost up the security, but I don't think that it's possible.

Comment: @Lnvz So does my answer solve your problem? If not, I really don't understand what you want.

Comment: @Barmar It does. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the row returned by the query and get the username from that.

```
if ($count == 1) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    header("Location: index/index.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need edit your query to something like this:

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE password='$encrypt_password' AND `username`='$myusername'";

    As if you have 
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count==1) {
    // it means your user is in a db and it could be marked as logged in

     header("Location: index/index.php");
    }
```

Comment: why did you decide to keep this `$_SESSION['mypassword']="$mypassword";`?

Comment: $myusername doesn't exist. I forgot to delete it. All the user enters is their password.

Comment: Lnvz u can't be serious

Comment: @Lnvz  select user from the table only by password is a bad idea,

Comment: @Drew today is the Friday  and beer, you know

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.